# Constant periodic Sobolev embedding

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Dear mathoverflowers,

I would like to have a reference regarding the optimal constant in the Sobolev embedding

$$
\|u\|_{L^q}\leq C_{s,q}\|u\|_{\dot{H}^s},
$$

($H^s$ denotes the standard L^2 Sobolev space $W^{s,2}$)

for zero mean periodic functions. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

PD: A reference on the slightly different embedding

$$
\|u\|_{L^q}\leq C_{s,q}\|u\|_{H^s}
$$

is also appreciated :-).